# WPhone 7 listbox update from XML

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox

I am having a problem with my Listbox not updating/refresing.I have read here that i need to use `ObservableCollection` but i didn't have any luck.I am populating my Listbox from a XML.

```
 public class PestotoraPost
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }

    }
void WebLoad()
    {
        WebClient pestotora = new WebClient();
        pestotora.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(pestotora_DownloadStringCompleted);
        pestotora.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("wwww.someURL.com/xml.php"));

    }
```

Note that the actual xml is a php containing the xml structure (from a sql DB)

```
 void pestotora_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        XElement doc = XElement.Parse(e.Result);
        listBox1.ItemsSource = from results in doc.Descendants("Data")
                            select new PestotoraPost
                            {
                                ID = results.Element("DataID").Value,
                                Date = results.Element("DataDate").Value,
                                Name=results.Element("DataName").Value,
                                Message=results.Element("DataMessage").Value     
                            };
    }
```

Everytime the XML changes,my Listbox won't update doing a `listBox1.UpdateLayout();`

Any clue/help on how to start implementing this one?
Thank you very much.

UPDATED

```
namespace pestotora
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            UIload(true);
            WebLoad();

        }

        public ObservableCollection<PestotoraPost> Posts { get; set; }

        public class PestotoraPost
        {
            public string ID { get; set; }
            public string Date { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Message { get; set; }
        }


        void WebLoad()
        {

            WebClient pestotora = new WebClient();
            pestotora.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(pestotora_DownloadStringCompleted);
            pestotora.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("www.domain.com/xml.php"));

        }

        void UIload(bool Splash)
        {
            if (Splash == true)
            {

                ApplicationBar.IsVisible = false;
            }
            else
            {

                ApplicationBar.IsVisible = true;
            }
        }

        void pestotora_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            //XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);

            XElement doc = XElement.Parse(e.Result);


            /* listBox1.ItemsSource = from results in doc.Descendants("Data")
                                select new PestotoraPost
                                {
                                    ID = results.Element("DataID").Value,
                                    Date = results.Element("DataDate").Value,
                                    Name=results.Element("DataName").Value,
                                    Message=results.Element("DataMessage").Value

                                }; */
            var list = from results in doc.Descendants("Data")
                       select new PestotoraPost
                       {
                           ID = results.Element("DataID").Value,
                           Date = results.Element("DataDate").Value,
                           Name = results.Element("DataName").Value,
                           Message = results.Element("DataMessage").Value
                       };
            Posts = new ObservableCollection<PestotoraPost>(list);
            foreach (var post in list)
            {
                Posts.Add(post);
            }

            UIload(false);


        }


        private void ApplicationBarMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //stckPost.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;

        }



        private void ApplicationBarIconButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Post.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }

        private void ApplicationBarIconButton_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            listBox1.UpdateLayout();
            //listBox1.ScrollIntoView(listBox1.Items[0]);

            WebLoad();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. If you use MVVM pattern**: In viewModel implement INotifyPropertyChanged and declare:

```
private ObservableCollection<PestotoraPost> _posts;
public ObservableCollection<PestotoraPost> Posts 
{
 get{return _posts;} 
 set
  {
     _posts = value;
     RaisePropertyChanged("Posts");
  }
 }
```

in xaml write:

```
<ListBox Name="listbox1" ItemsSource="{Binding Posts}"/>
```

in pestotora_DownloadStringCompleted method:

```
var list = from results in doc.Descendants("Data")
                            select new PestotoraPost
                            {
                                ID = results.Element("DataID").Value,
                                Date = results.Element("DataDate").Value,
                                Name=results.Element("DataName").Value,
                                Message=results.Element("DataMessage").Value     
                            };
Posts = new ObservableCollection<PestotoraPosts>(list);
```

---

**2. If you run everything in a code-behind** just declare

```
 public ObservableCollection<PestotoraPosts> Posts {get;set;}
```

And in Page constructor init collection:

```
 Posts = new ObservableCollection<PestotoraPosts>();
```

Xaml will have the same declaration.
And in `pestotora_DownloadStringCompleted` method:

```
var list = from results in doc.Descendants("Data")
                            select new PestotoraPost
                            {
                                ID = results.Element("DataID").Value,
                                Date = results.Element("DataDate").Value,
                                Name=results.Element("DataName").Value,
                                Message=results.Element("DataMessage").Value     
                            };
foreach(var post in list)
{
   Posts.Add(post);
}
```

**What have we done?**

In xaml we set a [databinding](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/data-binding-with-collection-and-xaml/) . Now `listBox1` will get data from `Post` collection.
Then we created new collection and notyfied `listBox1` to update it's view. (in first vatiant).

In second variant we populated collection and as it was observable it notifyed a list box.

Comment: Well it compiles without errors but there is no data! i have edited my post to include the new source code.

Comment: Put this line into constructor  *Posts = new ObservableCollection<PestotoraPost>();* and remove  this line *Posts = new ObservableCollection<PestotoraPost>(list);* from the method.